# Can I pass a generic object to an apex method?

Tags: apex

I would create a generic method which can take in input a generic object (not only an SObject)...

For example would create a method like:

```
public static output MyMethod(Object inputmessage, String Objpamaeter){
    inputmessage.put(Objpamaeter, 'xx');
    output xx= new outputValidation();
    xx.ouputparameter_1='Hi';
    return xx;
}
```

where `output` is an object with string parameteres, while `inputmessage` is an custom apex object or an SObject...
If an so large generalization is not possible, what solution can be taken to prevent the fragmentation of the architecture?

thanks in advance...

Klodjan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you could make such a method with the current reflection support in Apex.

I'd suggest creating an [interface](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_interfaces.htm) that all input classes implement. Then you could just deal with them via that common interface. E.g.

```
public interface Validatable {
    bool isValid();
}
```

The standard sObjects won't implement this interface, so you might need to wrap them in a wrapper class.

Comment: Thnk! it has been useful :D
As a workAround, I created a validation system, creating a map of the object like Map<String,Object> where the object is a standard sfdc object (string, Date, DateTime ecc...). After this I create a generic vadidator class which get in input a Map instead of a generic object.
I hope that what I wrote is clear :D